# When all is going, feed the Walrus

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

> When all is going but a dozen less half
>   Make sure to bring the Baker back.
>
> Once brought, proceed forward, but
>   Be sure to feed the Walrus from Beynac.
>
> Finally go to where these meet true,
>
> > Where less is nothing
> >     Where the past is divided
> >     Where the ends are one.

Using the above riddle cipher.

> What is the following? 
>  1000 1110 
>  0100 1111 
>  1001 1100 
>  1001 1101 
>  1111 0001 
>  0110 1111 
>  0000 0011 
>  1111 0011 
>  0110 1110

**Hint #1**

> Each stanza of the riddle is a step in encoding the cipher.

**Hint #2**

> The first stanza does refer to a number (and a little more) but 13 is not it.

Comment: Onion maybe? I converted binary to string and the result was "Oñoón".

Comment: @MCCCS Solving the riddle is critical in solving the puzzle.

Comment: If you look at the post's source text, you can see that the author has introduced some divs in places that don't quite line up with the line breaks. Interesting.

Comment: @MorganG Tried to utilize them :(

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Figuring out what the riddle is talking about is the most important part. Once you have that, the cipher will be easy to decrypt.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about this puzzle but I can offer what I found: Benyac is in France, Walrus in French is "Morse". I assume this is a key point.

Comment: @weejammaz Indeed. Now to figure out the rest of it :P

Comment: And I'm pretty certain the first stanza is talking about numbers;  a dozen less half and then baker would refer to 13, a bakers dozen.

I wouldn't be surprised if the numeric theme continued, with the 'divided' part of the last bit. E.g. no negatives, something to do with division, and where 1 is the first and last digit?

Comment: @AvikMohan - I have been thinking the same thing. In fact, I was just coming to post it. The first stanza probably refers to 6 and 13. I think "Where less is nothing" could refer to the number 1 (less than 1 is nothing).

Comment: Adding or subtracting 13 I doubt is the way to go, as this leads to impossibilities in representation in the given bits. Subtracting 13 brings us into negatives (and I doubt we're doing something like two's complement) and adding 13 brings us to 9 bits (assuming that 0000 0000 is zero, not 1, else it would work. But we need 0 im almost sure.... unless.....

Comment: Feed me hints!!

Comment: 12 less half *could* mean 12 - .5 = 11.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! I think I got it, the solution is:

> PUZZLINGSTACKEXCHANGE

Steps to solution:

**1.**

> **Walrus from Beynac**

details:

> Wikipedia says Beynac is 'a commune in western France', Walrus translates to french Morse, that suggests Morse code was used

**2.**

> **Oddly placed `<div>` tags amid binary numbers** (in the puzzle's edit history)

details:

> After splitting binary by `<div>` and substituting ones for dots and zeros for dashes and decoding message using Morse code I got WBGGSPUNZAHJRLEJOHUNL (also there is a new line at end of that string but I just ignored it)

**3.**

> **Number hidden in first stanza**

details:

> Dozen less half = 12 - 12/2 = 6 
>  Baker's dozen = 13 
>  Together it's 19

**4.**

> **Caesar cipher**

details:

> I guess last past of the riddle was supposed to guide me to Caesar cipher but I just blind guessed to use it :) 
>  Now we just need to apply 19 to shift string from step 2. Et voilà! 
>  ***OP Reason:*** Actually the first stanza's solution is this:
>  When all is going = rot
>  a dozen less half, be sure to bring the Baker back = 6+1 aka 7
>  So together they make rot7.
>  But this is how the cipher was made, so in actuality, rot19 is required to decipher it.

Comment: Correct answer, although #4 isn't the caesar cipher and it's not supposed to be 19 either lol. Well technically not.

Comment: What a coincidence. So what was the original intent? Can you give a hint?

Comment: "When all is going" as in "Qrpnlvat"  naq gur Onxre vf whfg bar zna, abg guvegrra   [Rot13](http://www.rot13.com/)

Comment: One thing to note. As per the first hint. The riddle is the steps to encipher the text, not decipher.

Comment: Nicely done. I'd forgotten about those divs - it never occurred to me to look at the markdown!

Comment: What has a [Viola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola) to do with this? :-)